# Private enum inside class

Tags: java, enums

I have a lot of classes where each class contains a map with completely different search keys. Each map has 4 items on average => 4 search keys on average.

Example:

```
class A
{
 private final static Map<String, String> properties;
 static
  {
    Map<String, String> tmp = new HashMap<>();
    tmp.put("NearestNeighbour", "INTER_NEAREST");
    tmp.put("Bilinear", "INTER_LINEAR");
    tmp.put("Bicubic4x4", "INTER_CUBIC");
    properties = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmp);
  }

  private enum InterpolationMode
  {
    NN("NearestNeighbour"),
    Bilinear("Bilinear"),
    Bicubic("Bicubic");

    private String mode;
    InterpolationMode(String mode) {
      this.mode = mode;
    }

    public String getMode(){
      return mode;
    }
  }
}
```

In this class my keys for map are `NearestNeighbour, Bilinear, Bicubic4x4` so I created a private enum and retrieve the value from map like this `properties.get(InterpolationMode.Bilinear.getMode());`

The problem is that I have about 20 classes and each class has it's own map with different keys ( they are not related ). The global package enum does not make sense for me since those search keys are not related in any way. Is it a good idea to create private enum like that in each class? Or is there a better way to do that and does not use enum at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using enums for this purpose is totally fine. What you could consider is using enums as keys (instead of strings) and using `EnumMap` instead of `HashMap`.

```
Map<InterpolationMode, String> tmp = new EnumMap<>(InterpolationMode.class);
tmp.put(InterpolationMode.NN, "INTER_NEAREST");
tmp.put(InterpolationMode.Bilinear, "INTER_LINEAR");
tmp.put(InterpolationMode.Bicubic, "INTER_CUBIC");
```

The advantage of `EnumMap` is that it is more compact and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating many classes just to hold different maps of data? If so, it is better to create only one class, then create many objects from that class.

Using global enums is ok, as long as the enums have real meanings (e.g. gender, types of bank accounts).

Comment: It is quite fine to create different classes as "scopes" for different enums/keys.